# Will jvm add the no argument constructor break the singleton of OSGi?

Tags: java, osgi

When we define a component using OSGi Declarative Services (DS), by default we are defining a singleton [link](http://njbartlett.name/2010/07/19/factory-components-in-ds.html). JVM will insert a no argument constructor if we are not defining any thing inside the class. By the above definition we are breaking singleton by allowing others to create instances. Can anybody please explain me the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Singleton does not mean the design pattern from [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). It means that Declarative Services will instantiate the class only once.

The same naming convention is used in [Spring](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm). Singleton means there that Spring will instantiate the bean only once.

Comment: You mean to say there are two singleton's available. one is GoF and other is DS singleton? Could you explain with some use case or some referrences?

Comment: Singleton is not a phrase that is only used in GoF book. For technologies like Spring and Declarative Services, it means that a class will be instantiated max once at the same time by the technology. Please see the "The singleton scope" chapter in the Spring documentation I linked! I linked Spring doc as I read "singleton scope" first in their documentation. Many say that by having IOT technologies in Java the GoF Singleton  pattern became an anti-pattern.